# Related to KMeans

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means

I am new to kmeans. My graph has clusters but has the same color. I need each cluster to have different colors. I tried many ways to do it, followed instructions, and worked hours, but I failed to do it. I also tried with sklearn.cluster. Here is the main code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def problem(xvalue, yvalue):
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(xvalue, yvalue, color="b")
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.title('KMeans Graph')
    plt.savefig('testing1.pdf')
    plt.show()
```

and here is the test driver.

```
from main code import problem

filename = input("Please enter a specific file name: ")
f = open(filename, 'r')
xvalue = []
yvalue = []
for line in f:
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    xvalue.append(float(line[0]))
    yvalue.append(float(line[1]))
print(xvalue)
# prints [40, 10, 200, 230, 40, 15, 220]
print(yvalue)
# prints [40, 10, 200, 231, 43, 45, 190]
result = problem(xvalue, yvalue)
```

Here is the image as an example of what I have.
[image: The image shows two clusters.]

Comment: This may help - https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/plot-k-means-clusters-python.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to call any code to calculate KMeans.